# Creating Segments in Video

Tags: python, pygtk, gstreamer

I'm using Python 2.7, PyGTK 2.24, and PyGST (Gstreamer).

To ensure smooth playback from one clip to another (without a blink), I combined all the clips I needed into one larger video. This lets me seek to the exact place I need in code. One of the clips is like a "fill-in", which should loop whenever one of the other clips is not playing.

However, to make my code easier and more streamlined, I want to use segments to define the various clips within the larger video. Then, at the end of each segment (I know there is a segment end event), I seek to the fill-in clip. When I need another clip, I just seek to that segment.

My question is, how exactly do I create these segments? I'm guessing that would be the  [event_new_new_segment()](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-reference/class-gstevent.html#function-gstevent--event-new-new-segment), but I am not sure. Can I create multiple clips to seek with using this function? Is there another I should use. Are there any gotchas to this method of seeking in my video that I should be aware of?

Second, how do I seek to that segement?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like only `GstElement`'s can generate `NEWSEGMENT` events, you can't simply attach it to an existing element. The closest thing you could do if not using Python, would be creating a [single shot](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstClock.html#gst-clock-new-single-shot-id) or [periodic](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstClock.html#gst-clock-new-periodic-id) `GstClockID` or and use [`gst_clock_id_wait_async`](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstClock.html#gst-clock-id-wait-async) until the clock time hit. But the problem is, `GstClockID` is [not wrapped](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380495) in PyGst.

I think I'm actually working on some similar problem. Some kind of solution I'm using now, is gluing video streams in real time with [gnonlin](http://gnonlin.sourceforge.net/). The good side: seems to work, didn't have time to thoroughly test it yet. Bad side: poorly documented and buggy. [These](https://code.flumotion.com/trac/browser/flumotion/component/producers/playlist/playlist.py) sources from the `flumotion` project (and the comments inside!) were very, very helpful to me for understanding how to make the whole thing work.

Comment: Frankly, abbot, this is about as close to an answer as I will probably ever get to this muddle, so you can have the bounty. What say we catch each other on chat sometime? Perhaps we can help untie the knots in each other's code.